# Copy a worksheet as new file with all cells as numbers instead of formulae

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet 'Form' that is populated with many cells with formulae based on Data in Worksheet 'Data' in the same workbook 'Master. After running a macro I want to save 'Form' as a new file such that, the cells all have values rather than  formulae, i.e they shouldn't depend on any sheet in 'Master'.

Secondly the name should be a string concatenated of contents in cell D3 and Cell D4 of the worksheet 'Form', but whereas cell D4 is a string, cell D3 is a date. I want to convert this date to `ddmmyyyy` format. The name of the file should be String Concatenate (D3,D4) -> 
`ddmmyyy XXXXXX.xlsx`

I have done this so far - but the cells in new file Format.xlsx are formulae rather than values and I dont know how to change the name to composed of the contents of two cells

D3 contains a date - 7/3/2019 and D4 contains a String - "XXXX"

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Add
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Format").Copy Before:=wb.Sheets(1)
wb.SaveAs Range("D3").Value & Range("D4").Value & ".xlsx"
```

Comment: Just add this to your code `wb.Sheets(1).Cells.Value = wb.sheets(1).Cells.Value` before the `SaveAs`

Comment: I get a runtime error saying 'Out of memory'. Did i understand right -- its the same values on both sides of the = ?

Comment: Then do this `wb.sheets(1).UsedRange.Value = wb.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Value`

Comment: That allows me save the file - as values - but what about the name of a date object to convert it to a string ?

Comment: That part would be `wb.SaveAs Format(Range("D3").Value, "ddmmyyyy") &  " " & Range("D4").Value & ".xlsx"`

Comment: Thats great - all solved. I would give you 'Accepted' - but its all in the comments :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Add
With wb
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Format").Copy Before:=.Sheets(1)
    .Sheets(1).UsedRange.Value = .Sheets(1).UsedRange.Value
    .SaveAs Format(.Sheets(1).Range("D3").Value, "ddmmyyyy") & " " & .Sheets(1).Range("D4").Value & ".xlsx"
End With
```